# I'm handling Client site from admin panel

Tags: php, laravel-8

i have created the admin panel where im saving every data, the main thing is the user want to add or edit data from admin panel for his site. its like a blog.
first i have done the slider section where im fetching data from admin panel to client site.
this is the slider section code which is working perfectly.
Add file

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1  class="">ARABIC SECTION</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-md-12 float-left">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title text-lg float-left col-md-12" >
                    Manage Home Section
                    <a  class="float-right btn btn-danger" href="{{ URL('/admin/post/list')}}">Back</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-header -->
            <div class="card-body">
                
                <div class="tab-content p-0">
                    <form action="{{ url('/arabicpost/submit')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                      @csrf
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="">Title 1</label>
                          <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="exampleInputTitle" placeholder="Enter Title 1">
                          @error('title')
                              <span>{{ $message }}</span>
                          @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="">Description 1</label>
                          <textarea class="form-control" name="description" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Description 1"></textarea>
                          @error('description')
                              <span>{{ $message }}</span>
                          @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="exampleInputFile">File input 1</label>
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="custom-file">
                              <input type="file" name="image" class="custom-file-input" id="exampleInputFile">
                              <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Choose file</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                              <span class="input-group-text">Upload</span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          @error('image')
                          <span>{{ $message }}</span>
                        @enderror
                        </div>
                        
                      </div>
                      <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="card-title text-lg float-left col-md-12">
                           Second Banner
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                      <div class="card-body">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Title 2</label>
                            <input type="text" name="title2" class="form-control" id="exampleInputTitle" placeholder="Enter Title 2">
                            @error('title2')
                                <span>{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Description 2</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="description2" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Description 2"></textarea>
                            @error('description2')
                                <span>{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputFile">File input 2</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                              <div class="custom-file">
                                <input type="file" name="image2" class="custom-file-input" id="exampleInputFile">
                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Choose file</label>
                              </div>
                              <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text">Upload</span>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            @error('image2')
                            <span>{{ $message }}</span>
                          @enderror
                          </div>  
                        </div>
                      <div class="card-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.card-body -->
        </div></div></div></div>

@endsection
```

List File

```
@extends('admin.layouts.app')
@section('main-content')
<div class="content-wrapper">

    <div class="card" style="margin-top:5%">
        <div class="card-header">
           <h2 class="text-center">English Home Section</h2>
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align: center; color:green; font-size:20px">{{session('msg')}}</div>
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align: center; color:red; font-size:20px">{{session('msgForDelete')}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-header">
          <a  class="btn btn-success" href="{{ URL('/admin/post/add')}}">Add Post</a>
         </div>
        <!-- /.card-header -->
        <div class="card-body">
           <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
              <thead>
                 <tr width="100%">
                    <th width="3%">ID</th>
                    <th width="10%">Title 1</th>
                    <th width="23.5%">Description 1</th>
                    <th width="10%">Title 2</th>
                    <th width="23.5%">Description 2</th>
                    <th width="10%">Image 1</th>
                    <th width="10%">Image 2</th>
                    <th width="10%">Action</th>
                 </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <?php  
                  // echo '<pre>';
                  // print_r([$result]);
                  // die();
               ?>
                 @foreach ($result as $list)
                 <tr>
                  <td>{{$list->id}}</td>
                  <td>{{$list->title}}</td>
                  <td>{{$list->description}}</td>
                  <td>{{$list->title2}}</td>
                  <td>{{$list->description2}}</td>
                  <td><img src="{{ asset('storage/app/public/post/'.$list->image) }}" width="150px"/></td> <td><img src="{{ asset('storage/app/public/post/secondbanner/'.$list->image2) }}" width="150px"/></td>             
<td><a  class="btn btn-primary" href="{{('/haffiz/admin/post/edit/'.$list->id)}}">Edit</a>
                     <a  class="btn btn-danger" href="{{('/haffiz/admin/post/delete/'.$list->id)}}">Delete</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                 @endforeach
                </tbody>
              <tfoot>
                 <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Title 1</th>
                    <th>Description 1</th>
                    <th>Title 2</th>
                    <th>Description 2</th>
                    <th>Image 1</th>
                    <th>Image 2</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                 </tr>
              </tfoot>
           </table>
        </div></div></div> </div>
@endsection
```

edit file

```
@extends('admin.layouts.app')
@section('main-content')

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1  class="">ENGLISH SECTION</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-md-12 float-left">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title text-lg float-left col-md-12" >
                    Manage Home Section
                    <a  class="float-right btn btn-danger" href="{{ URL('/admin/post/list')}}">Back</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-header -->
            <div class="card-body">
                
                <div class="tab-content p-0">
                    <form action="{{ url('/admin/post/update/'.$result['0']->id)}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                      @csrf
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="">Title</label>
                          <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="exampleInputTitle" value="{{$result['0']->title}}" placeholder="Enter Title">
                          @error('title')
                              <span>{{ $message }}</span>
                          @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="">Description</label>
                          <textarea class="form-control" name="description" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Description">{{$result['0']->description}} </textarea>
                          @error('description')
                              <span>{{ $message }}</span>
                          @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="custom-file">
                              <input type="file" name="image" class="custom-file-input" id="exampleInputFile">
                              <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Choose file</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                              <span class="input-group-text">Upload</span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          @error('image')
                          <span>{{ $message }}</span>
                        @enderror
                        </div>
                      
                      </div>
                      <!-- /.card-body -->
                      
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Title 2</label>
                            <input type="text" name="title2" class="form-control" id="exampleInputTitle" value="{{$result['0']->title2}}" placeholder="Enter Title">
                            @error('title2')
                                <span>{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Description 2</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="description2" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Description">{{$result['0']->description2}} </textarea>
                            @error('description2')
                                <span>{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputFile">File input 2</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                              <div class="custom-file">
                                <input type="file" name="image2" class="custom-file-input" id="exampleInputFile">
                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Choose file</label>
                              </div>
                              <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span class="input-group-text">Upload</span>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            @error('image2')
                            <span>{{ $message }}</span>
                          @enderror
                          </div>
                       </div>
                        <!-- /.card-body -->
                      <div class="card-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.card-body -->
            <section class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1  class="">ENGLISH SECTION</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-md-12 float-left">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title text-lg float-left col-md-12" >
                    Manage Home Section
                    <a  class="float-right btn btn-danger" href="{{ URL('/admin/post/list')}}">Back</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

@endsection
```

its Controller(Post)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Post extends Controller
{
    function listing()
    {
        $data['result'] = DB::table('posts')->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
        return view('admin.post.list',$data);
    }
    function submit(Request $req)
    {
      //validation
      $req->validate([
        'title'        => 'required',
        'description'  => 'required',
        'title2'        => 'required',
        'description2'  => 'required',
        'image'        =>  'mimes: jpg,jpeg,png',
        'image2'        => 'mimes: jpg,jpeg,png'
      ]);

      //storing image
      $image=$req->file('image');
      $ext = $image->extension();
      $file=time().'.'.$ext;
      $image->storeAs('public/post',$file);
      
      $image2=$req->file('image2');
      $ext2 = $image2->extension();
      $file2=time().'.'.$ext2;
      $image2->storeAs('public/post/secondbanner',$file2);


      //array
      $data = array(
        'title'        => $req->input('title'),
        'description'  => $req->input('description'),
        'title2'        => $req->input('title2'),
        'description2'  => $req->input('description2'),
        'image'        => $file,
        'image2'        => $file2,
                     

      );
      //inserting data
      DB::table('posts')->insert($data);
      $req->session()->flash('msg','Data has been Added'); 
      return redirect('/admin/post/list');
    }
    function delete(Request $req , $id)
    {
      DB::table('posts')->where('id',$id)->delete();
      $req->session()->flash('msgForDelete','Data has been Deleted'); 
      return redirect('/admin/post/list');
    }
    function edit(Request $req , $id)
    {
      $data['result'] = DB::table('posts')->where('id',$id)->get();
        return view('admin.post.edit',$data);
    }
    function update(Request $req , $id)
    {
      //validation
      $req->validate([
        'title'        => 'required',
        'description'  => 'required',
        'title2'        => 'required',
        'description2'  => 'required',
        'image'        => 'mimes: jpg,jpeg,png',
        'image2'        => 'mimes: jpg,jpeg,png'
      ]);
      //array
      $data = array(
        'title'        => $req->input('title'),
        'description'  => $req->input('description'),
        'title2'        => $req->input('title2'),
        'description2'  => $req->input('description2'),
      );
      
      if($req->hasfile('image'))
      {
        $image=$req->file('image');
        $ext = $image->extension();
        $file=time().'.'.$ext;
        $file2=time().'.'.$ext;
        $image->storeAs('public/post/',$file,$file2);
        $data['image']=$file;
      }

      if($req->hasfile('image2'))
      {
        $image2=$req->file('image2');
        $ext = $image2->extension();
        $file2=time().'.'.$ext;
        $image2->storeAs('public/post/secondbanner',$file2);
        $data['image2']=$file2;
      }
     
      //updating data
      DB::table('posts')->where('id',$id)->update($data);
      $req->session()->flash('msg','Data has been Updated'); 
      return redirect('/admin/post/list');
    }
}
```

and this is a controller where im sending data to client site.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\user;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EngHafizController extends Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        return view('user.english.login');
    }
    public function registration()
    {
        return view('user.english.registration');
    }
    
    public function homefront()
    {
        return view('user.english.index');
    }
   
    public function home()
    {
        $data['result'] = DB::table('posts')->get();
        return view('user.english.index',$data);
    }
  
    public function about()
    {
        $data['aboutresult'] = DB::table('abouts')->get();
        return view('user.english.about',$data);
        
    }
    
    public function whyhaffez()
    {
        return view('user.english.whyhaffez');
    }
   
    public function oursheikh()
    {
        return view('user.english.oursheikh');
    }
    
    public function contact()
    {
        return view('user.english.contact');
    }
 
}
```

This is all working properly.
lets get to the point. when try to do the same for ABOUT section
it give me the error which is
(Undefined variable: aboutresult (View:C:\xampp\htdocs\haffiz\resources\views\user\english\index.blade.php))
i do the same thing for about section

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class AboutController extends Controller
{
    function about_listing()
    {
        $data['aboutresult'] = DB::table('abouts')->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
        return view('admin.post.about.aboutlist',$data);
    }
    function about_submit(Request $request)
    {
      //validation
      $request->validate([
        'title3'        => 'required',
        'heading3'      => 'required',  
        'description3'  => 'required',
        'image3'        => 'mimes: jpg,jpeg,png'
      ]);
  
      //storing image
      $image3=$request->file('image3');
      $ext = $image3->extension();
      $file=time().'.'.$ext;
      $image3->storeAs('public/post/about_image',$file);
      //array
      $data = array(
        'title3'        => $request->input('title3'),
        'heading3'        => $request->input('heading3'),
        'description3'  => $request->input('description3'),
        'image3'        => $file,
      );
    
      //inserting data
      DB::table('abouts')->insert($data);
      $request->session()->flash('msg','Data has been Added'); 
      return redirect('/admin/post/about/aboutlist');
    }
    function about_delete(Request $request , $id)
    {
      DB::table('abouts')->where('id',$id)->delete();
      $request->session()->flash('msgForDelete','Data has been Deleted'); 
      return redirect('/admin/post/list');
    }
    function about_edit(Request $request , $id)
    {
      $data['aboutresult'] = DB::table('abouts')->where('id',$id)->get();
        return view('admin.post.about.aboutedit',$data);
      
    }
    function about_update(Request $request , $id)
    {
      //validation
      $request->validate([
        'title3'        => 'required',
        'heading3'      => 'required',  
        'description3'  => 'required',
        'image3'        => 'mimes: jpg,jpeg,png'
      ]);
      //array
      $data = array(
        'title3'        => $request->input('title3'),
        'heading3'        => $request->input('heading3'),
        'description3'  => $request->input('description3'),
      );
      
      if($request->hasfile('image3'))
      {
        $image3=$request->file('image3');
        $ext = $image3->extension();
        $file=time().'.'.$ext;
        $image3->storeAs('public/post/about_image',$file);
        
  
        $data['image3']=$file;
      }
      //updating data
      DB::table('abouts')->where('id',$id)->update($data);
      $request->session()->flash('msg','Data has been Updated'); 
      return redirect('/admin/post/about/aboutlist');
    }
}
```

aboutLIST

```
@extends('admin.layouts.app')
@section('main-content')
<div class="content-wrapper">

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
           <h2 >About Section</h2>
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align: center; color:green; font-size:20px">{{session('msg')}}</div>
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align: center; color:red; font-size:20px">{{session('msgForDelete')}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-header">
          <a  class="btn btn-success" href="{{ URL('/admin/post/about/about')}}">Add Post</a>
         </div>
        <!-- /.card-header -->
        <div class="card-body">
           <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
              <thead>
                 <tr width="100%">
                    <th width="">ID</th>
                    <th width="10">Title </th>
                    <th width="40">Heading</th>
                    <th width="15">Description </th>
                    <th width="10">Image </th>
                    <th width="25%">Action</th>
                 </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <?php  
                  // echo '<pre>';
                  // print_r([$aboutresult]);
                  // die();
               ?>
                 @foreach ($aboutresult as $aboutlist)
                 <tr>
                     <td>{{$aboutlist->id}}</td>
                     <td>{{$aboutlist->title3}}</td>
                     <td>{{$aboutlist->heading3}}</td>
                     <td>{{$aboutlist->description3}}</td>
                     <td><img src="{{ asset('storage/app/public/post/about_image/'.$aboutlist->image3) }}" width="150px" height="100px"/></td>
                  <td>
                     <a  class="btn btn-primary" href="{{('/haffiz/admin/post/about/aboutedit/'.$aboutlist->id)}}">Edit</a>
                     <a  class="btn btn-danger" href="{{('/haffiz/admin/post/delete'.$aboutlist->id)}}" >Delete</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                 @endforeach
                </tbody>
              <tfoot>
                 <tr>
                    <th width="4">ID</th>
                    <th width="10">Title </th>
                    <th width="40">Heading</th>
                    <th width="15">Description </th>
                    <th width="10">Image</th>
                    <th width="25%">Action</th>
                 </tr>
              </tfoot>
           </table>
        </div>
        <!-- /.card-body -->
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
 

@endsection
```

aboutedit

```
@extends('admin.layouts.app')
@section('main-content')

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1  class="">ENGLISH SECTION</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-md-12 float-left">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title text-lg float-left col-md-12" >
                    Edit About Section
                    <a  class="float-right btn btn-danger" href="{{ URL('/admin/post/about/aboutlist')}}">Back</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-header -->
            <div class="card-body">
                
                <div class="tab-content p-0">
                    <form action="{{ url('/admin/post/about/update/'.$aboutresult['0']->id)}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                      @csrf
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="">Title</label>
                          <input type="text" name="title3" class="form-control" id="exampleInputTitle" value="{{$aboutresult['0']->title3}}" placeholder="Enter Title">
                          @error('title3')
                              <span>{{ $message }}</span>
                          @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="">Heading</label>
                          <input class="form-control" name="heading3" id="" placeholder="Heading" value="{{$aboutresult['0']->heading3}}">
                          @error('heading3')
                              <span>{{ $message }}</span>
                          @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Description </label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="description3" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Description ">{{$aboutresult['0']->description3}}</textarea>
                            @error('description3')
                                <span>{{ $message }}</span>
                            @enderror
                          </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="custom-file">
                              <input type="file" name="image3" class="custom-file-input" id="exampleInputFile">
                              <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Choose file</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                              <span class="input-group-text">Upload</span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          @error('image3')
                          <span>{{ $message }}</span>
                        @enderror
                        </div>
                      
                      </div>
                        <!-- /.card-body -->
                      <div class="card-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.card-body -->
        </div>
       
    </div>

</div>

</div>

@endsection
```

this the index file where im fetching

```
 @foreach ($result as $list)
                <img src="{{ asset('storage/app/public/post/'.$list->image) }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                          <div class="col-12 text-left">
                                <h1 class="animated slideInDown">{{ $list->title }}</h1>
                                <svg class="animated slideInDown" width="128" height="9" viewBox="0 0 128 9" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                </svg>                           
                                <p class="animated slideInLeft">{{ $list->description }}</p>                              
                                <a href="#" class="animated slideInRight btn btn-gold btn-p">Read More</a>
                            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="{{ asset('storage/app/public/post/secondbanner/'.$list->image2) }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                                <h1 class="animated slideInDown">{{ $list->title2}}</h1>
                                <p class="animated slideInLeft">{{ $list->description2 }}</p>
                                @endforeach
                            </div>
```

about section

```
 @foreach($aboutresult as $aboutlist)
            <div class="col-xl-7 about-p">
                <h5 class="about-welcome">{{$aboutlist->title3}}</h5>
                @endforeach
```

Comment: So...where did you define `$aboutresult`? The error message is clear - it's telling you that variable isn't defined. It's unclear where you're expecting it to come from or what you expect it to contain. You haven't really explained the purpose of the code, and also the code snippets which actually contain `$aboutresult` are out of context.

Comment: where should i define this ?

Comment: We can't really answer that because of the reasons I gave above - you haven't explained the purpose of the code, we don't know what you expect $aboutresult to contain or what it should be populated from, and the snippets are out of context so we have no concept of what the full scenario is. You'll need to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function home()
{
    $data['aboutresult'] = DB::table('abouts')->get();
    $data['result'] = DB::table('posts')->get();
    return view('user.english.index',$data);
}
```